# Limitar texto no CKEDITOR

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

Estou tentando fazer um limitador de caracteres no CKEditor, porém não encontrei nenhuma maneira,o script que usava para limitar `<textarea>` não funciona quando estou utilizando o CKEDITOR.

Tentei utilizar o plugin 'wordcounter' que agora parece que *só conta, não limita*.

```
extraPlugins: 'wordcount',
                wordcount: {
                    showCharCount: true,
                    showWordCount: false,
                    charLimit: 7500
                }
```

**Alguém conhece algum script? que limita?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Existe um plugIn para o próprio CKEditor com o propósito de limitar o número de caracteres inseridos:

[**CKEditor Maxlength Plugin**](http://divgo.wordpress.com/2013/01/04/ckeditor-maxlength-plugin/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

Ficam os passos para implementar o mesmo:

1. Editar o ficheiro `config.js` e adicionar o seguinte:

   ```
   config.extraPlugins = 'maxlength';
   ```

   O resultado será algo deste género:

   ```
   CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

     // Define changes to default configuration here.
     // For the complete reference:
     // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

     config.extraPlugins = 'maxlength';

   };
   ```
2. Na `textarea` adicionar um dos dois seguintes atributos `maxlength="xxx"` ou `data-maxlen="xxx"` ficando algo deste género:

   ```html
   <textarea rows="5" name="ola" id="ola" cols="120" data-maxlen="255"></textarea>
   ```

Podes fazer o download do plugIn a partir [deste link](http://data.divgo.com.s3.amazonaws.com/maxlength.zip).

---

## Código do PlugIn

Nos comentários do PlugIn, um utilizador queixava-se de um erro referente ao uso do `hasAttr()`.
Por via das dúvidas segue o plugIn sem o uso do referido método:

```
/*
 * CKEditor Maxlength Plugin
 *
 * Adds a character count to the path toolbar of a CKEditor instance
 *
 * @package maxlength
 * @author Sage McEnery
 * @version 1
 * @copyright divgo 2012
 * based on Word Count plugin from : http://www.n7studios.co.uk/2010/03/01/ckeditor-word-count-plugin/
 */
(function () {
    CKEDITOR.plugins.maxlength = {
    };

    var plugin = CKEDITOR.plugins.maxlength;

    function doCharacterCount(evt) {
        var editor = evt.editor;
        if ($('span#cke_maxlength_' + editor.name).length > 0) { // Check element exists
            setTimeout(function () {
                var charCount = editor.getData().length;
                var wcTarget = $('span#cke_maxlength_' + editor.name);
                if (editor.config.max_length > 0) {
                    wcTarget.html("Character " + charCount + "/" + editor.config.max_length);
                } else {
                    wcTarget.html("Character: " + charCount);
                };

                if (charCount > editor.config.max_length) {
                    wcTarget.css('color', 'red');
                    editor.execCommand('undo');
                } else if (charCount == editor.config.max_length) {
                    editor.fire('saveSnapshot');
                    wcTarget.css('color', 'red');
                } else {
                    wcTarget.css('color', 'black');
                };
            }, 100);
        }
    }

    /**
    * Adds the plugin to CKEditor
    */
    CKEDITOR.plugins.add('maxlength', {
        init: function (editor) {

            var maxLengthAttr = $("#" + editor.name).attr("maxlength"),
                dataMaxLengthAttr = $("#" + editor.name).attr("data-maxlen");

            if (typeof maxLengthAttr !== typeof undefined && maxLengthAttr !== false) {
                editor.config.max_length = maxLengthAttr;
            } else if (typeof dataMaxLengthAttr !== typeof undefined && dataMaxLengthAttr !== false) {
                editor.config.max_length = dataMaxLengthAttr;
            } else {
                editor.config.max_length = 0;
            };

            setTimeout(function () {
                if (editor.config.max_length > 0) {
                    $(".cke_bottom").append("<span id='cke_maxlength_" + editor.name + "'>Character: " + editor.getData().length + '/' + editor.config.max_length + "</span>");
                } else {
                    $(".cke_bottom").append("<span id='cke_maxlength_" + editor.name + "'>Character: " + editor.getData().length + '/' + editor.config.max_length + "</span>");
                }
            }, 1000);

            editor.on('key', doCharacterCount);
        }
    });
})();

// Plugin options
CKEDITOR.config.max_length = 0;
```

<sup>Guardar num ficheiro com o nome `plugin.js` que deverá ficar numa pasta com o nome `maxlength`.</sup>

Comment: no firefox não funciona esse plugin...erro de hasAttr e é um erro que inviabiliza o uso, já que ele deixa de rederizar o ckeditor

Comment: @Dorathoto Trocaste o código do _plugIn_ pelo que eu meti na resposta? Eu alterei o _plugIn_ para evitar o uso do `hasAttr()`

Comment: não, acabei puxando o código do site, vou testar com o seu... achei q era igual..foi mal

Answer (score 1):

O plugin *wordcount* do *ckeditor* tem um parâmetro que limita a quantidade de caracteres.

Resolva o problema da seguinte forma:

```
showCharCount: true,
maxCharCount: 10
```

Substitua o valor 10 pela quantidade de caracteres que precisar.

Segue o link para a documentação do plugin: [Documentação do wordcount](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/wordcount)