# plugin maxlength no ckeditor não funciona

Tags: javascript, html, plugin, ckeditor, textarea

Preciso limitar a quantidade de caracteres no CKEditor.

Segui o passo a passo deste topico:
[Limitar texto no CKEDITOR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21986/limitar-texto-no-ckeditor)

Mas não deu certo. Abaixo as alterações feitas no meu codigo:

[image: ../ckeditor/config.js]

[image: plugin add no diretorio]

```
   <textarea id="desc" name="desc" data-maxlen="10" rows="7" cols="45"</textarea>
```

O ckeditor funciona, porem o plugin não.

Ps. tentei tambem add a pasta "maxlenght" dentro desta pasta plugin. Também não funcionou.

Algo errado na sua implementação?

Outra questão: como esse plugin funciona? ele não deixa passar os caracteres da quantidade escolhida? ou ele apresenta erro depois de enviar o formulario?

Desde ja agradeço.

Comment: Em vez de `data-maxlen="10"`, tenta `maxlength="10"`

Comment: Nenhum dos dois funcionam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar este código abaixo. Ele irá pegar o valor em `maxlength` e limitar a quantidade de caracteres no CKEditor.

**Textarea:**

```
<textarea name="editor1" maxlength="10" id="desc" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
```

**Código:**

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){            
    CKEDITOR.instances.desc.on('key',function(event){
       // cada código na array representa uma tecla
       // Ex.: backspace, delete, uparrow etc..
       var keys = [46,8,38,40,37,39,35,36,16,18];
        var keyCode = event.data.keyCode;
        if(~keys.indexOf(keyCode)){
            return true;
        }else{
            var textLimit = document.querySelector("#desc").getAttribute("maxlength");
            var str = CKEDITOR.instances.desc.getData().replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "");
            if (str.length >= textLimit) return false;
        }
    });    
};

CKEDITOR.replace('desc');
</script>
```

Comment: Usei exatamente o seu codigo. Copiei e colei. Ele limita os caracteres, mas a pagina para de reconhecer o ckeditor.

Comment: Veja que na resposta a linha `CKEDITOR.replace('desc');` é apenas um exemplo para iniciar o CKeditor. Se vc já iniciou em algum lugar, não precisa colocar essa linha.

Comment: Retirei a linha,  obtive o mesmo resultado.

Comment: Acho que o jeito vai ser expandir o campo no banco de dados para text e não limitar... Pelo menos com o CKEditor eu ja protejo o input contra invasões. (certo?)

Comment: Veja o teste que fiz funcionando: http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/ckeditor/teste.html

Comment: Estou usando o ckeditor 4

Comment: Na linha ''CKEDITOR.instances.desc.on('key',function(event){" um parentese esta sendo aberto, e fechado so ao fim do codigo. Isso esta correto?

Comment: : não. parentese. Era esse o erro. O codigo está assim: "CKEDITOR.instances.desc.on('key',function(event){". Deveria estar assim: "CKEDITOR.instances.desc.on('key'),function(event){".

Comment: Mas resolveu o meu problema. Agradeço muito